# Entity Framework Core with combined keys and active record

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Trying to migrade an old application with full history in all tables to a new Entity Framework Core and .Net Core application.

The data model calls for full history in all tables.

```
Ident   Id   Active   SomeColumn             ModifiedBy  Modified
-------------------------------------------------------------------
0       1    0        Initial value          123         2016-01-01  
1       1    0        Second value           123         2016-01-03
2       1    1        Current value          321         2016-01-05
3       2    0        Another old value      321         2016-01-07
4       2    1        Another current value  124         2016-01-08
```

Ident is sql identity column which is not very useful. It's the combination of Id and Active which makes the primary key. Only one row with a specific Id can have be active (1). But many with the same id can be inactive (0).

So selecting "current" data will always have be "where id=? and active=1". How to make EF use that when following relations?

Is it even possible to model this using EF core and code-first?

I have the option to choose another data model and migrate the data, but the functionality must remain (i.e. full history on all tables).

Comment: Have you tried to create a compose key for your entity (Fluent API)?

Comment: @H.Herzl: I have tried, but gotten stuck so to say. How to specify that it should not follow the Ident key, but rather Id and Active=1.

Comment: Maybe: Ident = Identity and PK, Id + Active = Unique

Comment: That will still make EF use Ident for property navigation which will be "wrong". I needs to use Id + Active. I think perhaps having separate "History" tables instead is the way to go.